# GSON newbie: parse a JSON string into into a double[] ref

Tags: java, json, parsing

Given

```
 String theJSON = "{\"fundingRates\": ["+
"-0.00811024530204814,-0.00811024530204814,-0.00523639835476781,"
"-0.00556478090396538,0.00119056866828458,0.000230747044382269,"+
"-0.00445402087571539,-0.00424534913554488,-0.00600219416905775,"+
"-0.0117388075769262,-0.00887855826135051,-0.0072704827246495]} ";
```

How would I write GSON code

to put these values into

```
double[] fundingRates;
```

?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833749/how-to-use-gson-to-parse-a-list-of-json-objects-with-nested-arrays/29834079#29834079

Comment: @Crazenezz this question you linked doesn't even mention GSON or Java

Comment: @macias sorry, I got the wrong link, I'll delete for the comment above. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
double[] fundingRates = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonParser().parse(theJson).getAsJsonObject().get("fundingRates"), double[].class);
```